# Maven can't find httpcomponents-client in repository

Tags: maven, repository

I am trying to add the Apache httpcomponents-client library to my Maven project. I have added a dependency to pom.xml (as found on http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1.1), but when building my Eclipse project Maven is unable to find and download the library.

I have made a test project which does nothing but include this library to ensure that it's not any other settings that cause problems:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>no.gundelsby.test</groupId>
<artifactId>NeedMyPackage</artifactId>
<version>0.1</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpcomponents-client</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Building this project results in the same error.

Other things I have tested:

- Tried building with vanilla installs of both Maven 2.2.1 and 3.0.3
- Had a friend build the test project on his computer to rule out local problems on my computer
- Changed the version from 4.1.1 to 4.1

For what it's worth I had the same problem a few days ago with org.easytesting.fest-swing, see pom dependency entry below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
    <artifactId>fest-swing</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You don't want httpcomponents-client as a dependency.  That's just the parent pom for the client-related modules.  I suspect you actually want `<artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>`.

Comment: Yes, that did indeed solve my problem. Thank you very much :)

Comment: +10 if I could... I was using the maven dependency provided by search.maven.org and had the same problem. I removed 'components-' from the core and client artifact IDs, and then I was able to get the jars I needed! Thanks again!

Comment: Whoever wrote these artifact names must've also been the person responsible for PHP's naming standards

Comment: I spent 3h trying to fix this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here a simple solution...
Its great for me...
You can downloar jar file from internet and add manually to project from netbeans or another IDE.
Here an example for you:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CkUH.png)

Search the downloaded jar in your computer
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJSWd.png)